# Querying for a numeric value in Excel VBA/SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel

So, I'm getting a No value given for required parameter error from the following SQL query:

```
query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(DAY, [Target Completion Date], DATE()) AS Cert FROM [Project Status$] WHERE Cert < 20"
```

I tried adding quotes to the filter value (ie: '20') but I'm not getting the correct values (obviously). If I were to remove the WHERE clause, it queries just fine. Initially, I was going to do the following:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM [Project Status$] WHERE [Days to Target Date] < 20"
```

But the values in the column [Days to Target Date] are computed like so and varies between signed integers and the string "Complete":

```
=IF(AD1="",IF(I1="","",J1-TODAY()),"Complete")
```

I couldn't use WHERE [Days to Target Date] < 20 since it's throwing a Data mismatch error so I opted to do a DATEDIFF calculation instead. Anyone knows what could be the case here? Here's the code and [the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLNDl.png) I'm working with so far:

```
Sub GetData()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conStr As String
    Dim wbFile As String

    Dim query As String
    Dim row As Long

    wbFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Status Sheet.xlsx"
    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & wbFile & _
        "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1"";"
    query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(DAY, [Target Completion Date], DATE()) AS Cert" & _
            " FROM [Project Status$] WHERE Cert < 20"
    row = 2

    initSheet

    cnn.Open conStr
    rs.Open query, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    ...

ErrorHandler:
    cnn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Edit: So finally got this thing sorted out thanks to winghei and Axel. Here's the query that worked:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM [Project Status$] " & _
        " WHERE DATEDIFF(""d"", DATE(), [Target Completion Date]) < 20" & _
        " AND [Days to Target Date] <> ""Complete"" "
        " ORDER BY [Days to Target Date] ASC"
```

Answer (score 0):

try. or see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f

> SELECT * FROM [Project Status$] WHERE DATEDIFF('d', [Target Completion Date], DATE()) < 20

Comment: Thanks @winghei. I suppose you meant query = "SELECT *" & _
       " FROM [Project Status$] WHERE CInt(Replace([Days to Target Completion],"Complete",0)) < 20" However, the value for that column varies from -x to x, 0s, and "Complete". So using 0 to replace "Complete" is not really plausible, and given the condition, it would also include the completed ones in the query result.

Comment: i actually updated the answer recently. try changing Day to  "d". Also, im not sure if cert > 20 will work. try ` "SELECT * FROM [Project Status$] WHERE  DATEDIFF("d", [Target Completion Date], DATE()) < 20"`

Comment: Got the same parameter required error using this code: query = "SELECT *, DATEDIFF('d', [Target Completion Date], DATE()) AS Cert FROM [Project Status$] WHERE Cert < 20"

Comment: try to use the sql i mentioned above. `Cert` on `WHERE` Clause is considered as a parameter and not a reference from your `SELECT` clause

Comment: @winghei: `query = "SELECT * FROM [Project Status$] WHERE DATEDIFF(""d"", [Target Completion Date], DATE()) < 20"`. Doublequotes within a string literal needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Axel oh right . I was thinking i used single quote

Comment: So this seems to get me through just fine, `query = "SELECT * FROM [Project Status$] WHERE DATEDIFF(""d"", [Target Completion Date], DATE()) < 20"` but I'm getting the wrong values. Did I get the DateDiff parameters correctly? Ie: if the Target Completion Date is on Sunday  (08/14), it should output 3 (given that it's a Friday where I am today). I'm still getting getting values above 20.

Comment: Its the other way round. Switch the dates

Comment: @winghei Yep, I keep getting those mixed up. Thanks winghei!